# Edit XML with CDATA using SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, simplexml, cdata

I've seen a lot of questions with good answers about how to load a XML string with CDATA, or how to write an element with CDATA content, but I haven't been able to find a way to edit a XML that already contains CDATA and keep those previous CDATA after using `$xml->asXML()`.

**Is there a way to edit a XML that already contains CDATA and keep those previous CDATA after using `$xml->asXML()` ?**

Look at this scenario:

```
<?php
$str_xml = "<myxml><mytag><![CDATA[In this content, 8 > 2 & 1 < 9, and 10 is a 10% of 100. ]]></mytag></myxml>";

try {
    echo "XML with CDATA: \n\n";
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($str_xml, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    echo $xml->asXML() ."\n\n";
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo "XML with CDATA: \n\n";
    echo $e->getMessage() ."\n\n";
}
?>
```

After running this sample, the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<myxml><mytag>In this content, 8 &gt; 2 &amp; 1 &lt; 9, and 10 is a 10% of 100. </mytag></myxml>
```

As you can see, this output XML string has not CDATA tag values anymore. It will not fail to load another `simplexml_load_string` with this output, but the existing CDATA tags are gone, and also the special characters are replaced by their corresponding html entities.

I need to know if there is a way to read any XML containing **any** number of CDATA node values, and that after using `$xml->asXML()`, the output string still contains the previous CDATA tag values.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML written out contains no CDATA nodes, because you told SimpleXML to get rid of them when you passed `LIBXML_NOCDATA`. To keep them, simply don't pass that option!

[Here's a live demo of the fixed version](http://3v4l.org/OJ8d2), as below:

```
<?php
$str_xml = "<myxml><mytag><![CDATA[In this content, 8 > 2 & 1 < 9, and 10 is a 10% of 100. ]]></mytag></myxml>";

try {
    echo "XML with CDATA: \n\n";
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($str_xml);
    echo $xml->asXML() ."\n\n";
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo "XML with CDATA: \n\n";
    echo $e->getMessage() ."\n\n";
}
```

All the answers and comments you have read telling you you need to pass that option in order to use CDATA nodes with SimpleXML are quite simply **wrong**. The only problem is that the output of `print_r`, `var_dump`, etc, doesn't give a full representation of the data accessible by SimpleXML; *that doesn't mean it's not there*.

To get at the text in your example XML, you just need to cast the element to string (some contexts, such as an `echo` statement, do this automatically). As in [this example](http://3v4l.org/jc1OG):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str_xml);
$tag_content = (string)$xml->mytag;
echo "Here is the content of the <mytag> node: $tag_content";
```

Comment: Excellent!. I never tried to handle it like this, as I always thought that handling CDATA tags would require special options, etc. Of course, adding CDATA tags would require the help of DOMDocument::createCDATASection (to name a way). Thanks!!